# Java - read register value by OBIS code with TCP client

Tags: java, tcpclient

I have connection to TCP server (ip,port) to which meter is connected. I'd like to read the specified data from this port because when I'm using standard read method it sends me the whole data stream which takes about 15 minutes to read. So my question: is there any method I can use to get one specified register's value using his OBIS code (1.1.1.8.0.255 - active energy taken) in java via TCP server?

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;


public class scratch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hostname = "ip (hidden)";
        int port = port (hidden);

        try (Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, port)) {


            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

            InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(input);

            int character;
            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();

            String test = "/?!\r\n";
            byte[] req = test.getBytes();
            out.write(req);


            while ((character = reader.read()) != '\n') {
                data.append((char) character);
            }

            System.out.println(data);


        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {

            System.out.println("Server not found: " + ex.getMessage());

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            System.out.println("I/O error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The message "test" send initiation request to meter and his respond is correct but I dont' know how to put flags (ACK STX ETX) in my request, I've tried something like this:

```
String test2 = (char)0x6 + "051\r\n";
byte[] req2 = test2.getBytes("ASCII");
out.write(req2);
```

But meter doesn't recognize it.

Comment: In general, it's better to show some sample code of what you have tried so far, but in seems like a case that you might use java streams, a simple search in google for "java tcp stream example" would get you a lot of ideas on how to solve this

Comment: @CamiloCasadiego I've edited my question.

Comment: https://www.gurux.fi/node/5415 - from this topic I've got request form

Comment: can you also explain what meter is? also as I mentioned before you should use streams, in this case, a buffered reader might be better than simple reader which only will complete when the input is done, check this out maybe you can get some ideas https://www.baeldung.com/a-guide-to-java-sockets

Comment: The meter is Elster A1500